# Swift UI - Improving quality of text after it has been rotated?

Tags: ios, text, swiftui, rasterizing

After using .rotationEffect on a Text() view it actually makes the text appear less crisp and blurry. I think this is due to it being Rasterised however I wondered if there is a way around this or perhaps way of improving the quality of the text after it has undergone rotation effect?

```
ZStack{
             Image("tile_empty")
              .resizable()
              .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
              .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 250, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: 250)
              .rotationEffect(.degrees(120.0 * Double(i) + 30))

             Text("\(self.globals.levels[self.globals.currentLevel].tiles[self.tilesIndex].subTiles[i].word)")
               .font(Font.custom("Prime", size: ScreenSize.screenWidth * 0.04))
               .foregroundColor(.init(hex: "F2E9E4"))
               .fontWeight(.semibold)
               .rotationEffect(.degrees(-120.0 * Double(i) + -30))<----- Causes blurry text
                         
}
```